# How can I access and control my PC/Laptop via Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

I want to access pc controls through google glass, is it possible? How can I proceed?

Comment: What sort of "PC Controls" do you want to access?

Comment: I mean to say full mouse control via glass. Like click, drag etc.

Comment: Sounds like you would need to develop a Glassware app that communicates with your PC using a server of some sort (perhaps over wifi) to do what you want. You want want to develop / use gesture recognition on Google Glass ....  The question, though, is why you would want to do this. What work process are you trying to handle? Using Google Glass as a remote controller for your PC might not be the best use of Google Glass.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather broad, but i will try to give some idea that can be modified many ways.

If your PC has static IP address - you can run application server like Java driven Tomcat or Jetty or PHP or .NET, develop endpoints (like web service) for actions you want to perform. Glass app can work with web-service over http/https (using http client).

If the computer does not have static IP address - then you will need the hosting with static IP and then use this host as a medium between glass and your PC. This approach allow many users with their computers. For multi-user you might want to develop some authentication/token exchange mechanics or use already developed ones.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you share such references or tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's still not available.

You can either try out some of the softwares that allow a user to connect to other users' systems from a peer-to-peer connection, i.e. TeamViewer etc. But you'll still have to wait for the Google Glass version of that app to come.

Until then, you'll have to kiss the laziness aside and control your PC from your mouse and keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

A possible use for Google glasses operating PC and tablets is for use by the disabled, non-speaking individuals with limited mobility. Eye gaze currently does not work for someone with limited head control.